# How to change the color of the text here in this HTML file?

Tags: html, css

How do I change the color of this text: You Have Already Earned Credit For This Link.

```
    <div id=\"myform\" style=\"visibility: hidden;\">
<font size=2><b>You Have Already Earned Credit For This Link.</b></font>
</div>
```

This is a PHP and HTML file. Thank you very much indeed!

Comment: hint: something goes in the style tag.

Comment: The "font" tag is deprecated. Learn how to use CSS. And this has nothing to do with PHP

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change a HTML5 input's placeholder color with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610497/change-a-html5-inputs-placeholder-color-with-css)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to change to font color by adding color=white like this:

```
   <div id=\"myform\" style=\"visibility: hidden;\">
<font size=2 color=white><b>You Have Already Earned Credit For This Link.</b></font>
```

Comment: This is old fashioned code, deprecated and could in theory stop working in the future, browsers are not obliged to support it. Using CSS is a much better solution - see the other answer

Comment: Not only should you not be using `color="white"`, you also shouldn't be using `size="2"`, `<font>`, or `<b>`. The other answer is on the right track, but it's also bad because it's nesting an unnecessary `<p>` tag inside of the `<b>`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do so by doing the following: Wrap your text in a paragraph tag, and apply the following CSS styling:

```css
p {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="myform">
<b><p>
You Have Already Earned Credit For This Link.
</p></b>
</div>
```

Comment: You can't put a `<p>` inside of a `<b>`. Paragraph tags are block, "bold" tags are inline; you can nest block elements inside of inline elements -- a browser might handle it, though it's not valid.

Comment: (for clarity, the previous comment has a typo and should say "you **can't** nest block element inside of inline elements")